# Simple Clojure example - getting an infinite loop

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I am trying to some code that simple prints out everything in a list.

1. I define numberList
2. I create a loop - If the list is empty, print out a message and exit out. Otherwise, get the first item in the list, print it out, and recur on the list with everything but the first element.

   ```
   (def numberList [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

   (loop [nums numberList]
       (when (empty? nums)
         (println "All done!"))
       (def first_item (first nums))
       (println first_item)
       (recur (rest nums))
   )
   ```

This code results in an infinite loop that prints "All done!" and null back to back.

Comment: (if (empty? nums)
      (println "All done!")
   (do (def first_item (first nums))
    (println first_item)
    (recur (rest nums))))

Because `(when ...` does not branch conditionally like `(if ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `loop` goes through all the forms you have supplied, and because the `when` offers you no else-form as your ending conditional-point, your loop `recur`s for ever, printing `nil` for your `(first nums)` (since it got empty) and `"All done!"`.

You should use `if` instead of `when`, which gives you this form:

```
(if test then-form else-form)
```

`if` evaluates the test, if it returns logical `true` evaluates the then-form, otherwise jumps to the else-form. 
Also do not use `def` in places other than the top level, so preferably before of your loop piece and not inside of it, because it gets defined every time your loop does a loop, which is unnecessary (it also just doesn't look so nice!)

So your loop could look like this:

```
(def number-list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

(loop [nums number-list]
  (if (empty? nums)
    (println "All done!")
    (do (println (first nums)) (recur (rest nums)))))
```

or:

```
(loop [nums number-list]
  (if (seq nums)
    (do (println (first nums)) (recur (rest nums)))
    (println "All done!")))
```

Also if you don't have any problem with other possibilities for looping over sequences, you could for instance also use `doseq` or `for` which does a list comprehension:

```
(doseq [nums number-list] (println nums)) 
(for [nums number-list] (println nums))
```